# How to 'bind' a element buffer array to vertex array object using direct state access?

Tags: opengl, vertex-buffer

For the other buffers there are functions like:

```
glVertexArrayVertexAttribOffsetEXT(
    this->handle,               // vao handle
    vbo.getHandle(),            // vbo handle
    index,                      // specifies the index of the generic vertex attribute to be modified.
    size,                       // number of components per generic vertex attribute
    vbo.getType(),              // specifies the data type of each component in the array
    normalized,                 // specifies whether fixed-point data values should be normalized
    stride,                     // specifies the byte offset between consecutive generic vertex attributes
    offset                      // specifies a pointer to the first component of the first generic vertex attribute in the array
    );
```

But i can't find a method for binding the element buffer to the vao. Or am i missing something there?

PS: does it make sense to add vertex-array-object and direct-state-access tags?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't find it because it's not part of it.

The DSA extension was designed prior to VAO being part of GL3.0, and modified later on to interact with it. I would not be surprised it's a hole in the specification. Feel free to contact the specification owner (listed at the top of the [extension](http://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/EXT/direct_state_access.txt))

Comment: I actually wrote him an email but got no response. No problem though ... i'll just continue doing it the 'old way'.