# Is the glVertexAttribPointer state bound to the current GL_ARRAY_BUFFER?

Tags: arrays, opengl, buffer, vertex, vao

I have a simple question. Is it right, that `glVertexAttribPointer` operations have to be called once for a `GL_ARRAY_BUFFER` to save the attribute states until I want to change them?
Or do I need to call `glVertexAttribPointer` each time in between `glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, ...);` and `glDrawArrays(...);` ?

Comment: You should probably know that since OpenGL 4.3 most of the VAO states can be set using direct state access.  There's an answer here about it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32739297/direct-state-access-with-vertex-buffers

Answer (score 3):

> Is it right, that glVertexAttribPointer operations have to be called once for a GL_ARRAY_BUFFER to save the attribute states until I want to change them? Or do I need to call glVertexAttribPointer each time.

[`glVertexAttribPointer`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glVertexAttribPointer.xhtml) specifies the location and data format of the array of generic vertex attribute at the specified index. This information is stored in the [Vertex Array Object](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Specification#Vertex_Array_Object). Note, in OpenGL there is always a vertex array object bound. Either the default vertex array object (0), which can't be deleted,  or a non-zero named vertex array object.

The specification of the vertex attribute arrays has to be done before an object is drawn:

```
glBindBuffer( ARRAY_BUFFER, posBufObj );
glEnableVertexAttribArray( 0 );
glVertexAttribPointer( 0, .... );
glBindBuffer( nvBufObj );
glEnableVertexAttribArray( 1 );
glVertexAttribPointer( 1, .... );

glDrawArrays( .... )
glDisableVertexAttribArray( 0 );
glDisableVertexAttribArray( 1 );
glBindBuffer( ARRAY_BUFFER, 0 );
```

Yes, it is sufficient to call [`glVertexAttribPointer`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glVertexAttribPointer.xhtml) once per vertex attribute. The [Vertex Specification](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Specification) is kept until it is not redefined, because it is stated in the [Vertex Array Object](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Specification#Vertex_Array_Object).
Of course, the buffer object, where [`glVertexAttribPointer`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glVertexAttribPointer.xhtml) refers to must not be deleted. Also the state, whether the vertex attribute is enabled ([`glEnableVertexAttribArray`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glEnableVertexAttribArray.xhtml)) or not is kept until the vertex attribute is disabled again ([`glDisableVertexAttribArray`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glEnableVertexAttribArray.xhtml)).
The Khronos OpenGL wiki about [Vertex Specification](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Specification) clearly says:

> The [`glVertexAttribPointer`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glVertexAttribPointer.xhtml) functions **state** where an attribute index gets its array data from.

This state can be retrieved with [`glGetVertexAttrib`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glGetVertexAttrib.xhtml).

More information about vertex attributes can be found in the [OpenGL CoreProfile specification](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/glspec46.core.pdf) from Chapter 10.2 to 10.6

To handle different vertex attribute pointers and not to specify and enable or disable them alternately, different [Vertex Array Objectx](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Specification#Vertex_Array_Object) can be generated ([`glGenVertexArrays`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glGenVertexArrays.xhtml)), which stores all the information about  data format, state, attribute index and the name of the vertex buffer object:

*generated and specify vertex array object*

```
vaoObj = glGenVertexArrays();
glBindVertexArray( vaoObj );
glBindBuffer( ARRAY_BUFFER, posBufObj );
glEnableVertexAttribArray( 0 );
glVertexAttribPointer( 0, .... );
glBindBuffer( nvBufObj );
glEnableVertexAttribArray( 1 );
glVertexAttribPointer( 1, .... );
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
glBindVertexArray( 0 );
```

*bind vertex array object*

```
glBindVertexArray( vaoObj );
glDrawArrays( .... )
glBindVertexArray( 0 );
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not understand your question well. But using glVertexAttribPointer must be used on your currently bound vbo :

```
glBindVertexArray(vao);
glBindBuffer(ARRAY_BUFFER, position);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
glVertexAttribPointer...
glBindBuffer(normal);
glEnableVertex...
glVertexAttribPointer...

....

glBindVertexArray(vao);
glDrawArrays...
```

Comment: I mean, if I bind a Buffer, then call glVertexAttribPointer, unbind the buffer and use it later to render some stuff, is it required to call glVertexAttribPointer again before rendering? Or does the glBindBuffer automatically uses the glVertexAttribPointer configuration?

Comment: Vertex attributes pointers are stored in the vao (which is required since 3.3). Whenever you bind the vao, all these settings get restored. You should also not bind buffers before every draw-call since the buffer bindings are also stored in the vao.