# OpenGL 4.5 Direct State Access Render a Triangle - GL_INVALID_VALUE

Tags: c++, opengl, opengl-4

## The Description

I'm currently learning OpenGL and want to try out the the direct state access extension from OpenGL 4.5. Thus I setup a simple triangle render example (in 3D) which should render my triangle. The code below is executed each frame and draws a triangle in 3D space.

```cpp
    void Geometry::draw(glm::vec3 pos, glm::vec3 pos1, glm::vec3 pos2) {
        float vertices[9] = {
            pos.x, pos.y, pos.z,
            pos1.x, pos1.y, pos1.z,
            pos2.x, pos2.y, pos2.z
        };

        unsigned int m_VaoID;
        glGenVertexArrays(1, &m_VaoID);
        glBindVertexArray(m_VaoID);

        unsigned int m_VboID;
        glGenBuffers(1, &m_VboID);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_VboID);
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

        glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
        glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(float) * 3, 0);

        Shader shader = Shader("../../shader.glsl");
        shader.compileShader();
        shader.useShader();

        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);

        glBindVertexArray(0);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
        glDeleteVertexArrays(1, &m_VaoID);
        glDeleteBuffers(1, &m_VboID);
    }
```

However, as soon as I change the code to make use of the direct state access extension, it no longer renders a triangle and instead produces error messages.

```cpp
    void Geometry::drawDSA(glm::vec3 pos, glm::vec3 pos1, glm::vec3 pos2) {
        float vertices[9] = {
            pos.x, pos.y, pos.z,
            pos1.x, pos1.y, pos1.z,
            pos2.x, pos2.y, pos2.z
        };

        unsigned int m_VaoID;
        glCreateVertexArrays(1, &m_VaoID);
        glVertexArrayAttribFormat(m_VaoID, 0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0);

        unsigned int m_VboID;
        glCreateBuffers(1, &m_VboID);
        glNamedBufferData(m_VboID, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

        glVertexArrayAttribBinding(m_VaoID, 0, m_VboID);

        Shader shader = Shader("../../shader.glsl");
        shader.compileShader();
        shader.useShader();

        glBindVertexArray(m_VaoID);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_VboID);

        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);

        glBindVertexArray(0);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
        glDeleteVertexArrays(1, &m_VaoID);
        glDeleteBuffers(1, &m_VboID);
    }
```

Both methods get called in my **update loop** with the same values (between -1.f and 0.f).

## The error output:

Here is the console output of the error I'm getting:

```
[OpenGL Debug HIGH] GL_INVALID_VALUE in glVertexArrayAttribBinding(bindingindex=16 >= GL_MAX_VERTEX_ATTRIB_BINDINGS)
[OpenGL Debug HIGH] GL_INVALID_VALUE in glVertexArrayAttribBinding(bindingindex=17 >= GL_MAX_VERTEX_ATTRIB_BINDINGS)
[OpenGL Debug HIGH] GL_INVALID_VALUE in glVertexArrayAttribBinding(bindingindex=18 >= GL_MAX_VERTEX_ATTRIB_BINDINGS)
[OpenGL Debug HIGH] GL_INVALID_VALUE in glVertexArrayAttribBinding(bindingindex=19 >= GL_MAX_VERTEX_ATTRIB_BINDINGS)
```

## What I tried so far

I looked through the Khronos Wiki and through the docs.gl documentation, but I could not find out why my code produces the above error instead of rendering my triangle.

Comment: The third parameter of `glVertexArrayAttribBinding` should not be a VBO. You are also missing calls to `glVertexArrayAttribFormat` and `glVertexArrayVertexBuffer`. I guess you confused completely how DSA works. Check out [Direct State access with vertex buffers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32739297/direct-state-access-with-vertex-buffers/32739484#32739484) for a step-by-step explanation on how to translate from old code to DSA. Also note, that you shouldn't call `glBindBuffer` when drawing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 3d parameter of [`glVertexArrayAttribBinding`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glVertexAttribBinding.xhtml) is not the vertex buffer object, it is a binding index. It is an arbitrary id which you have to choose.
The following instruction associates a binding index to an attribute index (0) of the specified VAO.

<s>`glVertexArrayAttribBinding(m_VaoID, 0, m_VboID);`</s>

```cpp
glVertexArrayAttribBinding(m_VaoID, 0, binding_index);
```

Furthermore you have to use[`glVertexArrayVertexBuffer`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glBindVertexBuffer.xhtml) to associate a buffer object to a binding index of a specified VAO:

```cpp
glVertexArrayVertexBuffer(m_VaoID, binding_index, m_VboID, 0, sizeof(float) * 3);
```

Comment: Thx for the answer. Could you please specify what the binding index is for? Can I just choose any random number? Interesting to know that I still have to call `glBindVertexBuffer` despite using DSA. I thought this would no longer be necessary.

Comment: @ShadowDragon 1. Yes random. 2. I've changed the answer.

Comment: @ShadowDragon: You shouldn't be using glBindVertexBuffer but glVertexArrayVertexBuffer.